# Copy content of fields from one public struct to another

Tags: rust

I'm working on modifying some code that was written by another party.  The purpose is to emulate a UniFi Security Gateway to get reporting in the UniFi Controller software. I'm planning to run the emulation on a Zotac Mini PC with 2 NICs running CentOS 8. So that I don't have to worry about additional NAT, I have the 2 NICs setup as a bridge.

The struct for each network device is defined as:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub(crate) struct UnixNetworkDevice {
    name: String,
    mac: MacAddr,
    interface: NetworkInterface,
    statistics: UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics,
}
```

When the struct is filled in for the eth0 device you get this (`wan_device` at the beginning is just my tag so I know what I'm looking at):

```
wan_device Some(UnixNetworkDevice {
    name: "eth0",
    mac: 00:01:2e:80:3e:1d,
    interface: NetworkInterface {
        name: "eth0",
        index: 2,
        mac: Some(00:01:2e:80:3e:1d),
        ips: [],
        flags: 69699
    },
    statistics: UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
        collisions: 0,
        multicast: 497,
        rx_bytes: 359185,
        rx_compressed: 0,
        rx_crc_errors: 0,
        rx_dropped: 26,
        rx_errors: 0,
        rx_fifo_errors: 0,
        rx_frame_errors: 0,
        rx_length_errors: 0,
        rx_missed_errors: 0,
        rx_nohandler: 0,
        rx_over_errors: 0,
        rx_packets: 1587,
        tx_aborted_errors: 0,
        tx_bytes: 74695,
        tx_carrier_errors: 0,
        tx_compressed: 0,
        tx_dropped: 0,
        tx_errors: 0,
        tx_fifo_errors: 0,
        tx_heartbeat_errors: 0,
        tx_packets: 474,
        tx_window_errors: 0
    }
})
```

I'm also pulling the same information from the Bridge device:

```
bri_device Some(UnixNetworkDevice {
    name: "bri0",
    mac: 00:01:2e:80:3e:1d,
    interface: NetworkInterface {
        name: "bri0",
        index: 5,
        mac: Some(00:01:2e:80:3e:1d),
        ips: [V4(Ipv4Network { addr: 192.168.113.2, prefix: 24 }),
              V6(Ipv6Network { addr: fe80::c8ee:a0ff:fe3a:3096, prefix: 64 })],
        flags: 69699
    },
    statistics: UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
        collisions: 0,
        multicast: 0,
        rx_bytes: 275467,
        rx_compressed: 0,
        rx_crc_errors: 0,
        rx_dropped: 0,
        rx_errors: 0,
        rx_fifo_errors: 0,
        rx_frame_errors: 0,
        rx_length_errors: 0,
        rx_missed_errors: 0,
        rx_nohandler: 0,
        rx_over_errors: 0,
        rx_packets: 1371,
        tx_aborted_errors: 0,
        tx_bytes: 68355,
        tx_carrier_errors: 0,
        tx_compressed: 0,
        tx_dropped: 0,
        tx_errors: 0,
        tx_fifo_errors: 0,
        tx_heartbeat_errors: 0,
        tx_packets: 345,
        tx_window_errors: 0
    }
})
```

The `wan_device` doesn't show any IP addresses, since that is assigned to the bridge.

Right now, when it tries to do a `clone()` of the `wan_device`, it fails because of the empty `ips` section in the struct. I would like to copy the IPS portion of the struct from `bri_device` to `wan_device`. I hope that is possible.

Here is an MRE that can be made into a project, including the Cargo.toml file after it.

This is the link to the ZIP file of the same:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pfxbmv49ra1jxs/Test-OpnFi.zip?dl=0

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate clap;
extern crate regex;
extern crate simple_logger;

/// Network interface for inform
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct OpnFiInformNetworkInterface {
    pub drops: usize,
    pub enabled: bool,
    pub full_duplex: bool,
    pub gateways: Vec<String>,
    pub ip: String,
    pub latency: usize,
    pub mac: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub nameservers: Vec<String>,
    pub netmask: String,
    pub num_port: usize,
    pub rx_bytes: usize,
    pub rx_dropped: usize,
    pub rx_errors: usize,
    pub rx_multicast: usize,
    pub rx_packets: usize,
    pub speed: usize,
    pub speedtest_lastrun: usize,
    pub speedtest_ping: usize,
    pub speedtest_status: String,
    pub tx_bytes: usize,
    pub tx_dropped: usize,
    pub tx_errors: usize,
    pub tx_packets: usize,
    pub up: bool,
    pub uptime: usize,
    pub xput_down: usize,
    pub xput_up: usize,
}
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub(crate) struct Config {
    pub inform_url: String,
    pub capability: Vec<String>,
    pub cfgversion: String,
    pub selfrun_guest_mode: String,
    pub led_enabled: bool,
    pub stun_url: String,
    pub mgmt_url: String,
    pub authkey: String,
    pub use_aes_gcm: bool,
    pub report_crash: bool,
}

use pnet::{
    datalink::{interfaces, NetworkInterface},
    util::MacAddr,
};
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::{fs, io, path};

#[derive(PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub(crate) struct UnixNetworkDevice {
    name: String,
    mac: MacAddr,
    interface: NetworkInterface,
    statistics: UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics,
}

impl UnixNetworkDevice {
    pub fn new(name: &String) -> io::Result<UnixNetworkDevice> {
        let device_path = path::Path::new("/sys/class/net").join(name);
        if !device_path.as_path().is_dir() {
            return Err(io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
                format!("Unable to locate UnixNetworkDevice {}", name),
            ));
        }

    let mac_string = fs::read_to_string(device_path.join("address"))?;
        if mac_string.trim().len() < 15 {
            return Err(io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::InvalidData,
                "Mac address is empty.",
            ));
        }
    let mac = MacAddr::from_str(mac_string.trim())
            .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, e))?;

        let interface = interfaces().into_iter().filter(|i| i.name == *name).next();
        if interface.is_none() {
            return Err(io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
                format!("Unable to locate NetworkInterface {}", name),
            ));
        }
    let interface = interface.unwrap();

        let statistics = UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics::new(name);

        Ok(UnixNetworkDevice {
            name: name.clone(),
            mac,
            interface,
            statistics,
        })
    }

    pub fn name(&self) -> String {
        self.name.clone()
    }

    pub fn mac(&self) -> MacAddr {
        self.mac
    }

    pub fn interface(&self) -> NetworkInterface {
        self.interface.clone()
    }

    pub fn statistics(&self) -> UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
        self.statistics.clone()
    }
}

// ===== Statistics =====

#[derive(PartialOrd, PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub(crate) struct UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
    pub collisions: usize,
    pub multicast: usize,
    pub rx_bytes: usize,
    pub rx_compressed: usize,
    pub rx_crc_errors: usize,
    pub rx_dropped: usize,
    pub rx_errors: usize,
    pub rx_fifo_errors: usize,
    pub rx_frame_errors: usize,
    pub rx_length_errors: usize,
    pub rx_missed_errors: usize,
    pub rx_nohandler: usize,
    pub rx_over_errors: usize,
    pub rx_packets: usize,
    pub tx_aborted_errors: usize,
    pub tx_bytes: usize,
    pub tx_carrier_errors: usize,
    pub tx_compressed: usize,
    pub tx_dropped: usize,
    pub tx_errors: usize,
    pub tx_fifo_errors: usize,
    pub tx_heartbeat_errors: usize,
    pub tx_packets: usize,
    pub tx_window_errors: usize,
}

impl UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
    pub fn new(device_name: &String) -> UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
        let read_value = |statistic_name: &str| -> io::Result<usize> {
            let stat_path = path::Path::new("/sys/class/net")
                .join(device_name)
                .join("statistics")
                .join(statistic_name);
            let value = fs::read_to_string(stat_path.as_path())?;
            usize::from_str(value.trim())
                .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput, e))
        };

        UnixNetworkDeviceStatistics {
            collisions: read_value("collisions").unwrap_or_default(),
        multicast: read_value("multicast").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_bytes: read_value("rx_bytes").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_compressed: read_value("rx_compressed").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_crc_errors: read_value("rx_crc_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_dropped: read_value("rx_dropped").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_errors: read_value("rx_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_fifo_errors: read_value("rx_fifo_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_frame_errors: read_value("rx_frame_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_length_errors: read_value("rx_length_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_missed_errors: read_value("rx_missed_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_nohandler: read_value("rx_nohandler").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_over_errors: read_value("rx_over_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            rx_packets: read_value("rx_packets").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_aborted_errors: read_value("tx_aborted_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_bytes: read_value("tx_bytes").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_carrier_errors: read_value("tx_carrier_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_compressed: read_value("tx_compressed").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_dropped: read_value("tx_dropped").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_errors: read_value("tx_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_fifo_errors: read_value("tx_fifo_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_heartbeat_errors: read_value("tx_heartbeat_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_packets: read_value("tx_packets").unwrap_or_default(),
            tx_window_errors: read_value("tx_window_errors").unwrap_or_default(),
        }
    }
}

impl From<UnixNetworkDevice> for OpnFiInformNetworkInterface {
    fn from(value: UnixNetworkDevice) -> Self {
        let interface = value.interface();
        let stats = value.statistics();
        let ip = interface
            .ips
            .iter()
            .filter(|ip| ip.is_ipv4())
            .next()
            .unwrap();
        Self {
            drops: stats.rx_dropped + stats.tx_dropped,
            enabled: true,
            full_duplex: true,
            gateways: vec![],
            ip: ip.ip().to_string(),
            latency: 1,
            mac: value.mac().to_string(),
            name: value.name().to_string(),
            nameservers: vec![],
            netmask: ip.mask().to_string(),
            num_port: interface.index as usize,
            rx_bytes: stats.rx_bytes,
            rx_dropped: stats.rx_dropped,
            rx_errors: stats.rx_errors,
            rx_multicast: 0,
            rx_packets: stats.rx_packets,
            speed: 1000,
            speedtest_lastrun: 0,
            speedtest_ping: 0,
            speedtest_status: "Idle".to_string(),
            tx_bytes: stats.tx_bytes,
            tx_dropped: stats.tx_dropped,
            tx_errors: stats.tx_errors,
            tx_packets: stats.tx_packets,
            up: true,
            uptime: 0,
            xput_down: 0,
            xput_up: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let matches = clap::App::new("OpnFi Device")
        .version("0.1.0")
        .author("James Parks <jrjparks@zathera.com>")
        .about("Emulates a UniFi device")
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("config")
                .short("c")
                .long("config")
                .value_name("FILE")
                .help("Sets a config file path to use")
                .takes_value(true),
        )
    .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("controller")
                .long("controller")
                .value_name("FILE")
                .help("FQDN or IP Address of UniFi Controller")
                .takes_value(true),
        )
    .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("wan")
                .short("w")
                .long("wan")
                .value_name("NIC")
                .help("Set the nic to report for WAN")
                .takes_value(true)
                .default_value("eth0"),
        )
    .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("lan")
                .short("l")
                .long("lan")
                .value_name("NIC")
                .help("Set the nic to report for LAN")
                .takes_value(true)
                .default_value("eth1"),
        )
    .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("bri")
                .short("b")
                .long("bri")
                .value_name("NIC")
                .help("Set the nic to report for BRIDGE")
                .takes_value(true)
                .default_value("bri0"),
        )
    .get_matches();

    let _wan_device = match matches.value_of("wan") {
        Some(wan_name) => {
            info!("Using {} as WAN device.", wan_name);
            UnixNetworkDevice::new(&wan_name.to_string()).ok()
        }
        None => None,
    };
    let _lan_device = match matches.value_of("lan") {
        Some(lan_name) => {
            info!("Using {} as LAN device.", lan_name);
            UnixNetworkDevice::new(&lan_name.to_string()).ok()
        }
        None => None,
    };
    let _bri_device = match matches.value_of("bri") {
        Some(bri_name) => {
            info!("Using {} as BRIDGE device.", bri_name);
            UnixNetworkDevice::new(&bri_name.to_string()).ok()
        }
        None => None,
    };

println!("wan_device {:?}", _wan_device);
println!("lan_device {:?}", _lan_device);
println!("bri_device {:?}", _bri_device);

            // Interfaces

println!("Wan_Interface");

            let _wan_interface: Option<OpnFiInformNetworkInterface> = match &mut _wan_device.as_ref()
            {
                Some(wan) => Some(wan.clone().into()),
                _ => None,
            };

println!("Lan_Interface");

            let _lan_interface: Option<OpnFiInformNetworkInterface> = match &mut _lan_device.as_ref()
            {
                Some(lan) => Some(lan.clone().into()),
                _ => None,
            };

println!("Bri_Interface");

            let _bri_interface: Option<OpnFiInformNetworkInterface> = match &mut _bri_device.as_ref()
            {
                Some(bri) => Some(bri.clone().into()),
                _ => None,
            };
}
```

```
[package]
name = "test_opnfi"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["Mike Schaffner <mcschaffner@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"
license = "Apache-2.0"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
toml = "0.5.5"
regex = "1.3.1"
rand = "0.7.2"
net2 = "0.2.33"
byteorder = "1.3.2"
serde = "1.0.103"
serde_json = "1.0.42"
sysinfo = "0.9.6"
reqwest = "0.9"
hex = "0.4.0"
pnet = "0.23.0"
clap = "2.33"
ctrlc = "3.1.3"
log = "0.4.8"
simple_logger = "1.3.0"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Comment: I updated the question to have an MRE, let me know if you have any suggestions on how to make this work.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question hits many rust specific questions. Types, size of types, livetime, optional values to just name a few.

Please read Shepmaster's comment and update your question. To give you a direction that may help: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/2289bbcf50caabe7bc0fb397e073e581

```rust
// #[derive(Clone)] dosn't work because the unknown size of `value`
struct A {
    value: [isize],
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct B<'a> {
    value: Option<&'a [isize]>,
}

fn main() {
    //let a: A = A { value: [1] };
    //let a1 = a.clone();
    let b: B = B { value: None };
    let b1 = b.clone();
}
```